# Getting errno EAGAIN on pthread_mutex_unlock()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pthreads, mutex

I am getting the following error in SAP Agent logs,

```
(5538F3C3.0122-3154:pthread_mutex_unlock.c,44,"pthread_mutex_unlock") errno EAGAIN
```

and after this agent goes to unresponsive state.
Is this the correct behavior for pthread_mutex_unlock() to return error code EAGAIN ?
If so can anyone help me to get insight for error handling in such case.

Comment: Where does the error message come from? From sources compiled by you? As this seems to happend on windows: Which PThread implementation are you using?

Comment: In case your code logs this error: You are aware that recent PThread implementations do **not set** `errno`, but on error **return** an equivalent value.

Comment: I had query that why pthread_mutex_unlock() throws such error ([EAGAIN] The mutex could not be acquired because the maximum number of recursive locks for mutex has been exceeded. ) while unlocking, as resource(mutex) is already acquired by the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Single UNIX Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html), at least up to issue 6, states that `pthread_mutex_unlock` can return EAGAIN if "the mutex could not be acquired because the maximum number of recursive locks for mutex has been exceeded".

Now that may not make a lot of sense because you're trying to *release* the mutex rather than acquire it but, since it's in the documentation (and has been since at least SUSv2), you probably should allow for it. Issue 7 of SUS no longer lists `EAGAIN` as a possible error of `pthread_mutex_unlock` but, since you're getting it, that's probably not the issue your implementation complies with.

The question on *how* to handle it is an interesting one. `EAGAIN` is the code you usually get for a non-blocking I/O operation and you're supposed to then try again later on. But regardless of the reason, an error return from `pthread_mutex_unlock` probably means the mutex has *not* been unlocked.

So if you're *not* trying again, that may be leaving the mutex locked when you think you've released it, and hence be the cause of your unresponsiveness later on as you try to lock it again.

You may want to try doing it a few times (perhaps with an increasing time between retries) then exiting. This may well need some re-architecting of your application so you don't lose data.

You should also watch out for the case where your thread is attempting to unlock a mutex that it hasn't *actually* locked. The SUS documentation linked to above states that, in some cases, unlocking a mutex which is either locked by another thread, or unlocked, is undefined behaviour. In some other cases, an error is guaranteed to be returned for this. This all depends on the mutex type (normal, error checked, recursive or default).

And, finally, make sure you're getting the error from the right place. Your log message has the word `errno` in it but you need to be clear that the error code is *returned* from the function, not stored in the actual `errno` variable.

Comment: You're thinking of `EINTR` for interrupted system call.  `EAGAIN` is the one that's allowed to be the same value as `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: The current version of POSIX (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) does not list `EAGAIN` for `pthread_mutex_unlock()` anymore.

Comment: @alk, that's a valid point so I've added it to the answer. Probably doesn't help OP in this particular case since they're _getting_ that error but it's good to note.

Answer (score 1):

In general `EAGAIN` is an encouragement to retry your call a little bit later, while it was actually impossible to realize it.

Are you sure that `unlock` was called on a locked mutex? Because unlocking an unlocked mutex leads to undefined behaviour. Read the manual carefully there is different behaviors depending on the mutex type.

Comment: yes i recreated the issue using a test code and got EAGAIN error while unlocking the unlocked mutex (unlocking mutex twice). But in actual source code it is not the case and through logs it seems count of lock gained and released are same. What can be the other causes of such error ?

Comment: Becareful with log counts, if you use threads it may be the case that orders of messages is not the order of calls, depending on the logging you use). Analyse you source code carefully to verify that lock/unlock is correct (very subtle race bugs exists in concurrency). Without the code I have no other clue, sorry.